# Windows 7 and python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I want to install python 2.7 to my computer, but I have a problem. I've already installed that .msi file from the python official website and now I have a folder C:\Python27 . I've set up environmental variables(system variables) like this: ....;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts  After I've restarted my computer I type to the command window 'python' but It sais:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I believe installing Python with [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/packages/python) would set things up right automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html)

> Python is not added to the DOS path by default. [This screencast](http://showmedo.com/videos/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96)
>   will walk you through the steps to add the correct entry to the System
>   Path, allowing Python to be executed from the command-line by all
>   users.

To add Python to system variables: (Computer > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables) You would goto your cmd instance, and put in `PATH = C:/Python27/`

Comment: once you set it up, you have to logout and log back in.

Comment: To add Python to system variables: (Computer > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables)
You would goto your cmd instance, and put in PATH = C:/Python27/